# Unable to establish connection with elasticsearch 8.1 (java)

Tags: java, docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, elasticsearch-rest-client

I have elasticsearch 8.1 running in docker with this docker compose file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.1.0
    container_name: es-node
    environment:
     - xpack.security.enabled=false
     - discovery.type=single-node
    volumes:
      - ./elastic-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    cap_add:
     - IPC_LOCK
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.1.0
    container_name: kibana
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOST=http://localhost:9200
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
```

I'm trying to make a simple GET request to the es cluster using the org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.

Request:

```
        Request request = new Request("GET", "_cluster/health");

        try {
            return restClient.performRequest(request).toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

Rest client initialisation:

```
        var hosts = buildClusterHosts(transportAddresses);
        restClient = RestClient.builder(hosts).build();

        if (isElasticSniffEnabled) {
            sniffer = Sniffer.builder(restClient).build();
        }

        var esTransport = new RestClientTransport(restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());
        
        elasticsearchClient = new ElasticsearchClient(esTransport);
```

Main method:

```
        var es = ElasticEightClient.builder()
                .transportAddresses("localhost:9200")
                .isElasticSniffEnabled(true)
                .build();


        System.out.println("Started elasticsearch with health: " + es.getHealth());
```

buildClusterHosts() method is correctly building an array of HttpHost (in this case only one) and provides it to the rest client builder.

In theory this should be enough, but I keep getting Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Timeout connecting to [/172.20.0.2:9200] and I'm not sure why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Tldr;

It seems you are confusing the `Transport port` and the `Rest Api port` of Elasticsearch.

## To Fix

You will first need to expose the port of the `transport layer`, which is `9300` by default

```yaml
services:
  elasticsearch:
    ports:
      - 9300:9300
```

Then update the main method

```java
var es = ElasticEightClient.builder()
         .transportAddresses("localhost:9200")
         .isElasticSniffEnabled(true)
         .build();


System.out.println("Started elasticsearch with health: " + es.getHealth());
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked after I exposed the 9300 port, but I'm still using 9200 to access the cluster. A bit confusing, thanks again!

Comment: Update, when I created the post I removed the Sniffer initialisation. The connection is successful without the 9300 exposer and without the Sniffer. If I add the Sniffer I get the Timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what was the problem. To use the Sniffer you need to add `http.publish_host=localhost` as environment variable in the docker compose file.